# Deploying mod_wsgi: Error loading MySQLdb module

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, httpd.conf, mysql-python

I want to deploy my django app using apache + mod_wsgi again. I seem to be getting this error 500 message Initially, I was told that I need the latest version of MySQLdb. After I had installed, I got this error message.

```
Error loading MySQLdb module: /tmp/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.4-linux-i686.egg-tmp/_mysql.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied
```

I am not sure really what the problem is. I believe it might have something to do with this line written in my httpd.conf.

```
WSGIPythonEggs /tmp
```

But it is set that that so it can read write & execute.

Comment: Why are you storing libraries in `/tmp`?

Comment: Are you not allowed to create an eggs cache in If I cannot put that line in my httpd.conf file, I will have this error`[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/.python-eggs``/tmp`?. Before, I could resolve this by having `WSGIPythonEggs /tmp`in my httpd.conf file. Now there are some problems from failing to map segment from shared object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELinux is most likely enabled. This exact issue is documented in mod_wsgi documentation.

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Secure_Variants_Of_UNIX

Answer (score 0):

Try a different directory than `/tmp` - according to [this question](http://forum.webfaction.com/viewtopic.php?id=571), it has the *t* permission set, which disallows users deleting files not their own.

And you still need the `WSGIPythonEggs` directive.

Update: According to [Graham Dumpleton's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182954/problem-with-deploying-django-application-on-mod-wsgi/5183240#5183240), the directive only works in embedded mode, not daemon mode. He gives a link to his wiki on [fixing Application Permission issues](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Access_Rights_Of_Apache_User%27), which suggests setting the variable in the `mod_wsgi` script module, not `httpd.conf`.

Comment: I have created a new directory called 'tmp2', I have change permissions to 755 and in my httpd.conf change, I have called WSGIPythonEggs /tmp2. This has not worked (rror`[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/.python-eggs``/tmp2`)

Comment: @Shehzad009, try 777 for permissions.

Comment: @John C: No that failed `Can't extract file(s) to egg cache` error again.

Comment: @Shehzad009, so the directory has full permissions, and it still doesn't work? Weird. I'm not sure why not, but I can say that when I had the same error (using uWSGI/nginx), I created a directory my user `/home/foo/eggs`, where `eggs` had full permissions (no *t*), and the directories above had *x* permissions so they could be searched. After running `uWSGI`, there was a new directory in `eggs`, called `MySql...egg-tmp`, owned by `uWSGI`.

Comment: @Shehzad009, after adding my update - I noticed that was *your* question. So his answer didn't work? Is this a new problem, or complications with the original problem?

Comment: This is new problem. Before if it would say `Can't extract file(s) to egg cache`. I would just type 'WSGIPythonEggs /tmp' in my httpd.conf since I am running in embedded mode so everything was fine. We had to reload our recently server, and this is the first time I have come across this error.